# In case +subjunctive /mandatory?

Tags: subjunctives

I am really confused about this. My teacher tells me that after "in case" I always have to use subjunctive and this is the only acceptable form. For example :
     "Take a coat in case it should get chilly tonight." 
instead of
     "Take a coat in case it gets chilly tonight." 
My problem is that I can't find this rule in any of the grammar books I have and what is more my coursebook's answer key never uses subjunctive after in case. My hunch is that using subjunctive after in case is old-fashioned, but I am not really sure given that it doesn't appear anywhere. Please help me understand this, thank you!

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+case+it+rains%2Cin+case+it+should+rain%2Cshould+it+rain&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20case%20it%20rains%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20case%20it%20should%20rain%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshould%20it%20rain%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 2):

The subjective is optional and not required after "in case".  It is correct to say "Take a coat in case it gets cold."

As noted in comments, "should" is a modal and not the subjuctive. The subjuctive would be "Take a coat in case it get cold." (Which most speakers would find strange.)

Comment: Subjective? *Subjuctive?  I think you mean subjunctive.

Answer (score 1):

> [1] *Take a coat in case it should get chilly tonight*.
>
> [2] *Take a coat in case it gets chilly tonight*.

I think your teacher is confused. The idiomatic "in case" does not license subjunctive clauses (we can't say *"Take a coat in case it get chilly tonight"), and in any case the presence of "should" rules out any possibility of the clause being a subjunctive.

In both examples, the preposition phrase "in case" is introducing a declarative content clause functioning as an adjunct of implicit purpose, where the meaning is *Take a coat in order to avoid getting cold if it gets chilly tonight.*

The only difference between the two is that [1] infers that it becoming chilly tonight is less likely than in [2].